# How can I exclude individual file types from URL forwarding with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect every url entered in the Browser to the index.php.

This also works with my Code. For Example:

```
url.com/test1/test2/test3
url.com/test1/test2
url.com/test1
```

The CSS, images and JS files are also always forwarded.
I now have to exclude files with certain extensions (css, js, jpg, png, pdf) from the redirection.

My code in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

My Code in the Index file where i import the css-file:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I enter "url.com/test" the integration of my css file works. When I enter "url.com/test/test2" the stylesheet file does not load.

Comment: Your rules say that should rewrite to index.php if files are not present, so I don't think so your css/jpeg etc files will be redirected because of these rules. Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file apart from these?

Comment: That's the full content. I have described my question again. it just doesn't work in the subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure to place your htaccess rules file into root directory. You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the explanation. It works now.

Comment: @fschneider, Your welcome, happy learning.